# Laravel Query Builder returning empty rows from 100k+ rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My **users** table has over 100K rows. I need to fetch them all for export purpose. But, when I use following code, it doesn't return anything. But, if I apply limit then it returns them. It basically returns 10K rows and when I provide 20K on limit, it doesn't return anything.If I use **mysqli_query**, it returns all well in the same server and DB.

```
$myRows = DB::table('users')->get();//returns empty
$myRows = DB::table('users')->take(10000);//returns 10,000 rows
$myRows = DB::table('users')->take(20000);//returns empty
```

I am new to Laravel.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update` if it's ok with memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [chunking (scroll to "Chunking Results From A Table" point)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) would be good option here.

```
DB::table('users')->chunk(10000, function($users) {
    //some connect code
});
```